# MySQL searching query?

Tags: mysql

I'm new to MySQL and want to know that if I have a table with 25 column and the first one of it is the "id". Would the computer render every time through the whole table to search the particular "id".

Comment: no you can mention the particular id in where clause. pls include what you are working on exactly to get proper help

Comment: It depends on your query

Comment: how does this depends on my query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you construct the query like `SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE table_id=$id;` then it will not render all table. 
And as @dku.rajkumar says in the comment, it depends on what you want to fetch and your query structure.

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on the query and also the STORAGE Engine you choose to use.

like MyIsam or InnoDb

example

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY
)ENGINE=MyIsam;

CREATE TABLE tablename (
    id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

there do exist difference in way tables are stored ,dependiing on storage engine , which certainly will reflect in the criteria mysql server (mysqld) performs search to cater your needs .